# Issue trying to retrieve data from contract using Web3 1.0

Tags: web3js, dapp-development, dapps

I feel like I must be missing something trivial here. I have a smart contract that populates an array of structs shown below. When trying to call `addNewQuestion('0x12345')` or `getQuestionListSize()` it seems like it is never adding a new Question struct to  `questionList`. When calling `getQuestionListSize()` it should be returning the counter which I named `questionId` but it is always just returning "1". Any help greatly appreciated.

Contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract EthUpVoting {

  struct Question {
    bytes32 ipfsHash;
    uint upvotes;
    address user;
  }

  uint private questionId;
  mapping (uint => Question) public questionList;

  event AddedQuestion(bytes32 ipfs_hash, uint qId);

  function EthUpVoting() public {
    questionId = 1;
    questionList[questionId] = Question({
        ipfsHash: "Hello, World!",
        upvotes: 0,
        user: msg.sender
    });
  }

  function addNewQuestion(bytes32 questionHash) public {
      questionId += 1;
      questionList[questionId] = Question({
          ipfsHash: questionHash,
          upvotes: 0,
          user: msg.sender
      });
      AddedQuestion(questionHash, questionId);
  }

  function voteForQuestion(uint qId) public {    
    questionList[qId].upvotes += 1;
    questionId += 1;
  }

  function getQuestionTextAtIndex(uint qId) public constant returns (bytes32 ipfsHashReturn) {
      return questionList[qId].ipfsHash;
  }

   function getQuestionListSize() public constant returns (uint size) {
      return questionId;
  }

}
```

NodeJS:

```
const web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || "ws://127.0.0.1:8546")
const ethUpVotingContract = new web3.eth.Contract(config.eth.abi, config.eth.contractAddr);

ethUpVotingContract.methods.addNewQuestion('foo').send(ethOptions, (err, resp) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err) 
    } else {
      // successfully returns transaction hash 
      console.log(resp);
    }
}).then(resp => {
    // successfully returns transaction receipt
    console.log(resp);
});

ethUpVotingContract.methods.getQuestionListSize().call().then(function (resp) {
    // this always returns "1"
    console.log(resp);
});
```

Comment: why do you use ethUpVotingContract.methods. not just ethUpVotingContract

Comment: I was just following the documentation: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call

Comment: In a previous version 'ws' provider was not working, I'd try 'http' and/or 'ipc' to check if they work, web3 v1.0 is still in beta so some things will not work and others have bugs.

Comment: @Ismael so this methods thing is part of web3js 1.0 as new features?

Comment: @Etherkimist Yes, web3 v1.0 is a refactorization from the old stable v0.20. I'd say learn web3 v1.0 because it is more future proof, but if you need something production ready I'd stick with v0.20 for the time being. Hopefully v1.0 will be released soon.

Comment: Tried using the `http` provider, same symptoms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried your contract and found a couple of issues:

```
ethUpVotingContract.methods.addNewQuestion('foo')
.send(ethOptions, (err, resp) => {
```

Will fail with

> throw new Error('Given parameter is not bytes: "'+ value + '"');
>
> Error: Given parameter is not bytes: "foo"
>          at SolidityTypeBytes.formatInputBytes [as _inputFormatter]

Converting to bytes will make it work

```
const question = web3.utils.asciiToHex('foo');

ethUpVotingContract.methods.addNewQuestion(question)
.send(options, (err, hash) => {
```

The other problem is that now `send` and `call` return a promise. What is happening? If the `call` promise start executing before the `send` has finished it will display the previous data as if the `send` have never succeeded.

To fix that you have to make the `call` inside the then clause of the `send` to ensure it has finished

```
const message = web3.utils.asciiToHex('foo');

ethUpVotingContract.methods.addNewQuestion(message)
.send(options, (err, hash) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  console.log(`TxHash: ${hash}`);
})
.then((result) => {
  console.log('Send has completed');
  // Here we are guarantee `send` has finished
  // and we can query the data
  ethUpVotingContract.methods.getQuestionListSize().call()
  .then((result) => {
    console.log('Call has returned');
    console.log(result);
  });
});

// If we call here perhaps `send` didn't finish yet
console.log('Send was called');
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to find the mistake and explain everything, very helpful.